# How to ensure that operations on unsigned integers do not result in wrap

Tags: c, error-handling, unsigned, gcc-warning

I have two unsigned integers and I need to calculate the differences between them & store it in a signed variable

```
unsigned int var1, var2;
signed int diff;
diff = (signed)var1 - var2;
```

Can this lead to wrap becuase both var1 & var2 are unsigned?
Where is the **temporary difference** of both stored before getting assigned to diff. If that is signed variable then it wouldn't wrap else it should wrap.

On similar lines,
can we do like this -

```
var1 - var2 > signed_int_max
```

Assume var1 < var2 in such cases will my var1-var2 wrap before even getting compared?

Is this correct way to do ? Again if I get to now how temporary operations are stored before comparison , I'll get my answer.

Comment: You're going to have problems any way you do it, because (assuming 32-bit int) the difference between two unsigned ints can be anywhere from -4 billion to +4 billion, but the range of the signed int is only -2 billion to +2 billion.

Comment: @user3386109 yes ! That's true. But anyways if I assume my var1 and var2 are well within the range of signed then how is the temporary result stored and even in that case if var2>var1 will my result wrap or will it give a negative value.
eg var2 = 2 var1 = 1 so will my ans be diff = -1 or diff = wrapped value

Comment: Technically, the answer is implementation defined. With two's complement, the answer will be diff = -1, because the bit pattern of the wrapped value will be interpreted as the signed integer value -1. However, since you are assuming that both var1 and var2 are within the range of a signed int, you should just convert them both to signed before doing the subtraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming two's complement.

Given two unsigned integers `var1` and `var2`, the type of `var1 - var2` is `unsigned int` that may lead to overflow when storing to `signed int`. To determine overflow or not, you can do things like `var1 - var2 > INT_MAX` where `INT_MAX` will be implicitly converted to `unsigned int` before comparison.

In the case where `var1 < var2`, the result of `var1 - var2` will still be of type `unsigned int` and may be wrapped in case of underflow. E.g., `0 - UINT_MAX` will result in `1`. In this case, I suggest you to swap `var1` and `var2` and then determine accordingly. Something like

```
  if (var1 >= var2) {
    if (var1 - var2 > INT_MAX) // overflow
    else // good
  }
  else {
    if (var2 - var1 > INT_MAX + 1u) // underflow
    else // good
  }
```

Comment: if we store this diff in signed value and we assume that both are well within range of signed. and var2 > var1 which means ans should be negative. But will it wrap because unsigned diff is temp stored in unsigned temp ?

Comment: Assume var1 < var2 in such cases will my var1-var2 wrap before even getting compared?